# Laravel filter Restaurants by Category ID

Tags: laravel, where-clause

I creating multiple filter Restaurants.
This is categories relations on Restaurant model:

```
public function categories()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class,'restaurant_categories_relation','restaurant_id');
}
```

This is filter Restaurant Controller

```
public function filter(Request $request)
{
    // Kiểm tra ajax
    if(!$request->ajax())
    {
        return "";
    }

    // Lọc theo thành phố & quận
    if(!$request->city && !$request->district)
        $restaurants = Restaurant::with('categories');
    elseif($request->district)
        $restaurants = Restaurant::with('categories')->where('district_id', $request->district);
    else
        $restaurants = Restaurant::with('categories')->where('city_id', $request->city);

    // Kiểm tra có tìm kiếm hay ko
    if(!empty($request->input('query')))
    {
        $restaurants = $restaurants->join('restaurant_translations as t', 't.restaurant_id', '=', 'restaurants.id')
            ->where('t.locale','=', LaravelLocalization::getCurrentLocale())
            ->where('t.name', 'like', '%'.$request->input('query').'%')
            ->select('restaurants.*');
    }

    //Kiểm tra có lọc theo danh mục hay ko
    if(!empty($request->input('category')) && $request->input('category') != 0)
    {

    }
    foreach($restaurants->get() as $restaurant) {
    }
    ...
    return $html;
}
```

If have request filter category, I want to get restaurant have categoryID = request category ID. I do something im my script but it seen not working. Who can tell me how to do it? Thanks so much!

Comment: Please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52479091/filter-function-in-laravel/52479157#52479157)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `whereHas()`

```
if(!empty($request->input('category')) && $request->input('category') != 0) {
    $restaurants->whereHas('category', function (Builder $q) {
        $q->where('id', $request->input('category'));
    });
}
```